# group_by creates new variable with list of values within group - not sum

Tags: r, dplyr

If I'm grouping by one value, say by three different integers, but there is also another categorical column, is there a command where I can list all the categorical columns within this group as one long string.

I've tried using `paste` with a separator but it didn't work.

Here's what I've tried:

```
x <- x1 %>% 
  group_by(y) %>% 
  summarize(
    zlist = paste(z) #containing the list of numeric variables to identify which z values are grouped by y

  ) %>%
  arrange(desc(zlist)
```

Comment: Since `paste` works you need to show us what you tried.

Comment: There is a bit weird naming of the args in `paste`, check `collapse=`.

Comment: Use `zlist = paste(z,collapse=" ")` (or whatever separator you want)

Comment: please create a reproducible example plus your desired outcome